# Kruskal-Szekeres spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, wormholes

How does one determine the Kruskal Szekeres regions?
I know the Schwarzschild solution in Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates is given by 
$$(ds)^2 = \frac{32(GM)^3}{r}\exp(-r/2GM)(-dT^2 + dX^2) + r^2d\Omega^2,$$

where $X,T$ are the usual KS coordinates. What I want to know is how does one get this (please see image) from the above? If one was to try to re-create the image is it simply a matter of taking a range of values for both $r$ and $t$ in $X$ and $T$ and plotting the result?

[image]

**Edit:** Still having no luck with this. Here's what I've been doing. I'm just using maple to do it. 
I've defined coordinates $R$ and $T$. Set $2GM=1$ and then opted for a

`plot3d([R(r,t),T(r,t)],r=0..1,t=-4..4)`

I'm generating ouput like below:

[image]

Now, this is taking the correct form, sort of. I can identify two hyperbolae indicating global singularities but It's not exactly what I'm after. Any information would be great!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are asking? Are you asking how we find the lines corresponding to the event horizons (the dashed lines) and the singularities (the blue and green lines)?

Comment: @JohnRennie what I'm looking for is to produce an image like this myself. Of course, the blue and green lines correspond to $r=0$ and the dashed lines are the Schwarzschild singularity. How would one reproduce this image themselves with computer software such as MAPLE, Mathematica or MAXIMA for example. What would be the process do you know?